# How to Build and run the cordova project with eclipse and run project for android

Tags: android, cordova

I have created the project with cordova CLI but i do not know where i need to change and how to run the cordova android project with eclipse for each platform. Thanks for helping

Comment: why vote negative. its really facing problem for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before run the android project inside your Cordova Project you should know these things.
 If you are making any changes in the Cordova Project then first you need to prepare the cordova. use the command `cordova prepare`

Then it changed in your `config.xml` (for android) automatic as you added or any changes you made. Do not make any change in your android project which exist inside your Cordova project. You can only make change inside the `www` folder of your Cordova project. And after made changed you need to make cordova prepare every time.

After prepare the cordova you can run the android project on device or emulator. For this you make sure you have made the path of android sdk for `platforms-tools` and `tools` in your environment system. If you not configure this path and add this two path in system environment .
Now run the android project on device use command `cordova run android` and run on emulator use this command `cordova emulate android`.

And if want to run on eclipse then you should import this android project of your workspace in eclipse. But if you again made changes in your cordova project then need to delete and again import the android project this switching happened every time so better to run through CLI.

I hope you got all things

Answer (score 0):

Sunil's answer is good. I would like to add **logging** using `Android Debug Bridge`(**adb**).
You may want to run:
`adb logcat` 
 on a seperate shell window for `logs` after running `cordova run android` you need when you run into `errors`.This will produce `huge` logs, so I would recommend using:

```
adb logcat|grep Cordova
```