# creating application using cordova cli, add platform, build successfull but from eclipse that application not working properly

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

When i create application using `Cordova CLI`, add platform, build
successful, run successful but from `Eclipse` that application not
working properly.

I run contact application from `Cordova CLI`, its working fine, display
all contacts. But when i run that application from `Eclipse` it doesn't
display contacts. Blank screen display only.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You haven't given enough information about what you've done so far. Did you run "cordova build android" and "cordova prepare" on your project? How did you import the project into eclipse? Did you do it correctly? Are you getting any warnings or errors in eclipse?

Comment: [link]http://puu.sh/ehkXr/de9dd7a572.png

Comment: I am building application by running command "cordova build android" after that "cordova run android" then its show contact number as per in screenshot..

here is application snap...http://puu.sh/ehkXr/de9dd7a572.png

when i import to eclipse and run application, it causing issue.. Here is snap of how i import to eclipse
http://puu.sh/ehle9/090db3a78d.png

and here i run application from eclipse
http://puu.sh/ehlln/2ed1fed94b.png

and here i got result 
http://puu.sh/ehlED/e47b3a0942.png

@ruffles

Answer (score 0):

You're question was too vague to give you a proper answer, but read these to get a starting point on solving it yourself.

This : (Read the section on migrating with ADT)
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html

And this :
[How to Build and run the cordova project with eclipse and run project for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017868/how-to-build-and-run-the-cordova-project-with-eclipse-and-run-project-for-androi)